# Insert a string and add 0.5 in the last element in every list after

Tags: list-manipulation

How to insert a string after every 3rd list and then add 0.5 on every Z on every list after?

> Input:  `{"X1","Y1","Z0"},{"X2","Y2","Z0"},{"X3","Y3","Z0"}...{"X100","Y100","Z0"}`
>
> output: `{"X1","Y1","Z0"},{"X2","Y2","Z0"},{"X3","Y3","Z0"},{"Randomstring"},{X4,Y4,Z0.5}`

Comment: I strongly encourage you to learn the basics about "list manipulation". It's one of the most important things when working with mathematica.

Comment: I've made a partition, then joined the string and made If ContainsStringsQ change Z->Z+0.5 for every 3rd part. But my list is pretty long and it crashes. So I was wondering if there was an easier way or something.

Comment: This is a very ill-posed question. We expect questions to be formulated more precisely than this on this site. Do you really mean `{X4, Y4, Z0.5}`? Or do you mean `{"X4", "Y4", "Z0.5"}`? Further, what do you mean by "add 0.5 on every Z after ..."? Do you mean `{"X4", "Y4", "Z0.5"}, .., {"X100", "Y100", "Z0.5"}`?

Comment: I mean "X4" as in a string. Every 3rd element (the last element in the 3rd) in the list should be added by 0.5 **Example: `{"X4", "Y4", "Z0.5"}` .. `{"X6", "Y6", "Z1"}`**

Comment: Does another random string get inserted after `{"X6", "Y6", "Z1"}`? Or same random string as after` {"X3","Y3","Z0"}`? Please edit your question to clarify your intent. People will often miss clarifications made in a comment.

Comment: You ask for `{"X4", "Y4", "Z0.5"} .. {"X6", "Y6", "Z1"}`. Why not  `{"X4", "Y4", "Z0.5"}, {"X5", "Y5", "Z1"}`, `{"X6", "Y6", "Z1.5"}`.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list =
  {{"X1", "Y1", "Z0"}, {"X2", "Y2", "Z0"}, {"X3", "Y3", "Z0"},
   {"X1", "Y1", "Z0"}, {"X2", "Y2", "Z0"}, {"X3", "Y3", "Z1"},
   {"X1", "Y1", "Z0"}, {"X2", "Y2", "Z0"}, {"X3", "Y3", "Z2"}};

step = 3;
```

Add 0.5 to last element at every `step` positions

```
rep =
 StringTake[#, 1] <>
   ToString[ToExpression@FromCharacterCode@Rest@ToCharacterCode[#] + 0.5] & /@
      list[[All, -1]][[step ;; ;; step]]
```

> {"Z0.5", "Z1.5", "Z2.5"}

Replacement positions

```
pos = Transpose[{#, Array[-1 &, Length@#]}] &[Range[step, Length@list, step]]

{{3, -1}, {6, -1}, {9, -1}}
```

Replacement

```
sol = ReplacePart[list, Dispatch@Thread[pos -> rep]];
```

Insertion

```
Insert[sol, "RandomString", List /@ Range[Length@pos + 1, Length@list, step]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]